# Does mod_rewrite work for windows servers too?

Tags: windows, apache, mod-rewrite, iis-7

Does mod_rewrite work for windows servers too?  If not, how does windows use regular expressions the same way you can using the .htaccess file in Apache?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [URL Rewriting module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) for IIS7, shipped by Microsoft. It can *import* rules from mod_rewrite.  It doesn't have 100% compatibility, but most of what you want to do, it can do.

There are also other, third-party URL rewriters, with varying degrees of mod_rewrite-compatibility, and varying price points.  Helicon ISAPI Rewrite is a commercial one.

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) is a good one. Free, mostly compatible. Works on IIS6 or 7.  I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean for IIS, there are ways to do it.

In the project I am working on right now, we use [Helicon ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

Comment: I guess he indeed meant IIS as "iis7" is listed under the tags.